# How do you display a Libgdx particle effect on a white background?

Tags: java, rendering, libgdx, particle-system

Currently in my `render()` the background colour is set to white but when I change it to white I cannot see my effect at all.

I was wondering whether there was an option I need to enable or a line of code I might have missed?

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    effect.update(delta);
    effect.draw(batch);

    batch.end();

}
```

//here is the .p file

```
Untitled
- Delay -
active: false
- Duration - 
lowMin: 3000.0
lowMax: 3000.0
- Count - 
min: 0
max: 200
- Emission - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 250.0
highMax: 250.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Life - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 500.0
highMax: 1000.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 3
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 1.0
scaling2: 0.3
timelineCount: 3
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.66
timeline2: 1.0
- Life Offset - 
active: false
- X Offset - 
active: false
- Y Offset - 
active: false
- Spawn Shape - 
shape: point
- Spawn Width - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Spawn Height - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Scale - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 32.0
highMax: 32.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Velocity - 
active: true
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 30.0
highMax: 300.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Angle - 
active: true
lowMin: 90.0
lowMax: 90.0
highMin: 45.0
highMax: 135.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 3
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 0.0
scaling2: 0.0
timelineCount: 3
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.5
timeline2: 1.0
- Rotation - 
active: false
- Wind - 
active: false
- Gravity - 
active: false
- Tint - 
colorsCount: 3
colors0: 1.0
colors1: 0.12156863
colors2: 0.047058824
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Transparency - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 1.0
highMax: 1.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 4
scaling0: 0.0
scaling1: 1.0
scaling2: 0.75
scaling3: 0.0
timelineCount: 4
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.2
timeline2: 0.8
timeline3: 1.0
- Options - 
attached: false
continuous: false
aligned: false
additive: true
behind: false
- Image Path -
particle.png
```

don't know how to make the .pfile look code like apologies :(

Comment: Show the rendering code else we can't help.

Comment: Add it to the question. And please add the effect.p or show us which effect it is, if it's a lot transparent or even white you won't see it. That code is fine for sure.

Comment: so yeh i don't see any option in the .p file that will let me display a particle effect on a white background ?

Comment: also effect is definitely not white it is the default orange and red

Comment: There is nothing like that. If the effect is transparent or the png is transparent that can happen test it with a different particle

Comment: i checked the particle.png (image file) and it is on a transparent background if that is the case then what colour should the background of the particle image be ?

Comment: no that it has a transparent background is fine. Is the effect on a blackscreen white? if so do change the color of it.

Comment: Tested it. Meight be a bug of libgdx. With a white background no effect is visible even if you change texture color or stuff like that. But well regulary you should have any background so that shouldn't be a problem. Go ask that question inside of the badlogic forum.

Comment: I thought so because I followed their guides religiously.

Answer (score 12):

Disable additive blending in your particle effect.

Comment: Are you sure you replaced the file with the new one that has disabled additive blending? can you post how your new file looks like now? (in your original post)

Comment: That fixed it for me